# Chef's docker_image resource not working as expected in the docker cookbook

Tags: docker, chef-infra, cookbook

I have set up an AWS ecr Docker registry that I can manually pull an image down from using this command (after logging in):

```
docker pull 354026083790.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev-nginx
```

But this docker_image block does not work:

`docker_registry "https://354026083790.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" do
  username "AWS"
  password "lolololollol..."
end`


`docker_image "https://354026083790.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev-nginx" do
  tag node  latest
  read_timeout 7200
  write_timeout 7200
  action :pull
  host "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
end`

This errors with:

```
no such image: https:/354026083790.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev-nginx:latest: invalid reference format
```

I've tried several variations of this format and nothing seems to be working... any ideas? Note the http:/ instead of http:// on the error message.

Comment: Why do you have a scheme on it at all?

Comment: Removing that get's me "no basic auth credentials" however there is a login code block above that which seems to work since logging in to the instance after a failed run allows me to pul the image with the manually command above with out having to run docker login.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full recipe.

Comment: Ok I included the rest of the docker code in the cookbook.